# Deleting tableview row and posting request logic

Tags: swift, uitableview, backend, shopping-cart, delete-row

[image]

I'm trying to understand the logic when deleting multiple cell quickly and post the request. When i'm just deleting one cell it's working fine but when i try to delete multiple cell only the first cell is deleted.
My app flow currently:

1. Tap trash icon
2. Post data to backend
3. If successful, show message "Item successfully deleted".

Is it possible to make swift code more efficient and tap trash icon quickly to remove several items from cell or is it only possible in backend?

Comment: I have worked on such tasks. But never got this issue. I am sure you are missing something in backend.

Comment: Logic should be like: You send array of items to backend API, And a loader must start loading in Frontend until API response arrive. According to response you should perform action in Frontend.

Comment: Okay so the issue is not from mobile/swift right? @Kudos

Comment: Nope. It should be backend issue.